# Increase max java thread on linux

Tags: linux, multithreading

i am running a linux Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS on open VZ virtualization server and have the problem that i can not start more the 1000 threads in java before i get a OutOfMemoryError.
I have written a smal programm to test the max threads

```
 private static Object s = new Object();
    private static int count = 0;
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        for(;;){
            try {
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    public void run(){
                        synchronized(s){
                            count += 1;        
                            if(count % 1000 == 0) {
                                 System.err.println("New thread #"+count);
                            }
                        }
                        for(;;){
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                            } catch (Exception e){
                                System.err.println(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
            }catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to create new native thread current threads: " + count);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

every time i run this is stops between 1010 - 1040 threads, even my windows pc can handel 100000 threads where is the problem in linux? Any body have a idea wy this is? my user limits are:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1547020
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 99999
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 10240
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 99999
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

EDIT:
Also this is not user dependen if user1 runs 500 threads user2 can only start 500 more

Comment: What other applications are in use? Is your heap size REALLY unlimited? Does increasing the -Xmx value do anything?

Comment: -Xmx dosent work, I dont know how you mean REALLY unlimited

Comment: You should do some rudimentary memory profiling and get back to us with the results so we can tell you what's actually going on. This might be a hardware or virtualized hardware limit.

Comment: Also this is not user dependen if user1 runs 500 threads user2 can only start 500 more